# Weird colors in normal map baking

Tags: texture-baking, baking, normal-map

This drives me crazy! I tried many times, always wrong. Please help me with this.

It is the default cube in the default scene. I duplicated one, added a subdivision surface modifier and added some ring cuts. Applied the modifier.
In the bake set-up, it is like this:

[image]

When I bake, I get this:

[image]

### [The Blender file is here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HqkaDpUNK-ImBLK9HV5nkLznReQQxnMI/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

Unplug the *Image Texture* for the moment as the high poly also uses it, and give a bit of extrusion to the bake as the faces of the 2 cubes are overlapping, and it will work:

[image]

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!